# running bash script remotely and do some interaction between server and local

Tags: bash

I have a script in my local:

```
rsh $server /usr/path/scriptB
```

So basically it just runs "scriptB" on remote server.

On server, I have "scriptB"

```
echo "1. Walk"
echo "2. Run"
echo "3. Exit"

read -p "Please enter option and press RETURN: " option
case $option in
  1) 
     echo "Selected Walk"
     read -p "Please enter your name: " name
     echo $name
     ;;
  2)
     ...
esac
```

I created a simple menu in scriptB and ask user to type option (1-3), if user enters 1 then ask user to enter his name and print it out.

After running this script, it can display the original menu properly

```
1. Walk
2. Run
3. Exit
```

However it doesn't show the line

```
Please enter option and press RETURN:
```

but I am able to type the option. After entering "1" the program shows

```
Selected Walk
```

then it hangs and never goes further, whatever I type in the prompt. I have to kill it each time.

Does anyone know where the problem is? How to fix my script on both local and remote server? Thank you

Comment: If this is bash your missing the double semicolons (;;) in your case: ie. last line should read `echo $name ;;`. As for hanging, if this is rsh and your not running this in a loop - it's likely just exiting.

Comment: @JGreenwell Sorry I do have (;;) in my bash just missing here; otherwise it won't let me to compile the script.

Comment: What version of bash (`bash --version`) as this works fine on my system with 4.3 (can't remember when prompt flag was added). Alternatively you could just echo then read

Comment: @JGreenwell Is working for you? Could you see the "Please enter option and press RETURN:" after running the original script locally? And could you see the prompt "Please enter your name:  ?"

Comment: yes, locally, to both. so either the error is elsewhere in the code or caused by the environment (like bash version or shebang pointing to wrong shell).